# Are DataSet primary key columns indexed?

Tags: c#, dataset, linq-to-dataset

I'm writing a quick utility app with out of the box win forms and data sets.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(_maxTimestamp == null) return;

   var newRows = commonLogTableAdapter.GetDataByTimestamp(_maxTimestamp.Value);
   foreach (var row in newRows.Where(c => !dataSet1.CommonLog.Rows.Contains(c.Id)))
   {
      dataSet1.CommonLog.ImportRow(row);
   }
}
```

Will the lookup to see if the row already exists have the performance of a hash lookup or could it end up searching the whole collection over and over again?

The documentation for [DataRowCollection.Contains Method (Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hc992ac(v=vs.100).aspx) doesn't say.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a dictionary that will provide a hash for any column

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>> dict = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Col A"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());​
```

If each key has only one value use this

```
            Dictionary<string, DataRow> dict = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Col A"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());​
```